# incomplete type as member of std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, incomplete-type

I came about the same issue as described here
[Can't allocate class with forward declared value in std::map member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119722/cant-allocate-class-with-forward-declared-value-in-stdmap-member-variable)
in our codebase.

Hoever I also found other cases where our compiler (MSVC 2017) is able to compile this...
After fiddling around with the code I found that defining the con- & destructor in the cpp allows the files to compile.

In `test.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <map>
struct Incomplete;

class Test {
    std::map<int, Incomplete> member;
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    int foo() { return 0; }
};

#endif
```

In `test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"
struct Incomplete {};
Test::Test() {}
Test::~Test() {}
```

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

int main() 
{
    Test test;
    return test.foo();
}
```

## Why does defining the con- & destructor in the cpp file allow member-std::map-variables to use incomplete types?

Comment: Because `Incomplete` becomes complete at that point as you've placed `struct Incomplete {};` above constructor/destructor definitions.

Comment: *defining the con- & destructor in the cpp* as opposed to what?

Comment: It looks like you "discovered" that if you name a method...even a destructor...in your interface file then it requires a definition in your implementation file.  The inline method in the interface doesn't need a definition in implementation.  Looks like proper design to me.

Comment: As opposed to using the compiler generated ones or defining them in the header

Comment: @TomasDittmann If you declare something, you need to define it. By the way, show an example where your problem is arising, not your solution

Comment: If you are going to store an incomplete type in an STL container, you are better off storing it by reference or (smart) pointer.  The size of the reference or pointer will be the same regardless of the size of the incomplete object.

Comment: I wouldnt want a smartpointer in the map if i can use pseudo-forward-declared types

Comment: @Amadeus My question was why this works, not how I can get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because declaring the class member does not require `Incomplete` to be complete, but *invoking the `std::map` destructor does*, because it necessarily needs to invoke the `Incomplete` destructor to destroy the map contents.  (Invoking the default `std::map` constructor *could* require the type to be complete, depending on the implementation.  I'm not sure if the spec puts any requirements on this.  I can think of at least one implementation that would not require complete types.)

If you rely on the compiler to generate implicit ctors/dtors for you, that means that the type must be complete when the class definition is encountered, because that's when the compiler is going to implicitly generate the ctor and dtor.  It's as though you wrote `inline Test::Test() {} inline Test::~Test() {}` immediately following the class definition.  The dtor is implicitly going to destroy the map, which is going to destroy the map contents by calling `~Incomplete()` on any stored values, which we can't do without a definition for `Incomplete`.  And there, the whole thing falls apart and you get an error.

However, if you tell the compiler (by way of the `Test` ctor/dtor declarations) that *you* will be implementing them later, then it won't generate them, therefore no `std::map` ctor/dtor invocation gets compiled at that point.

Then you complete the `Incomplete` type prior to defining the ctor/dtor yourself, so the `Incomplete` ctor/dtor invocations *can* be successfully compiled.  If you remove the definition of `Incomplete` then you will run into the same error.

---

Note that, as others have said, you can side-step this issue by storing pointers/references to the incomplete type in the map instead.  A pointer or reference to an incomplete type is actually itself a complete type.  However, this may not be desirable in all cases so I'm hesitant to push that solution without knowing more details about how the map will be used.

Comment: And part of the danger is that deleting an incomplete type is undefined behavior, with the compile most often not running the destructor.