# In c++ there is a way to create a tree-like map that contains maps as a value?

Tags: c++

In c++ there is a way to create a tree-like map that contains maps as a value?

```
map<string, map<string, map<string, map<...>>> name;
```

Comment: Looks like you are most of the way there. What's the problem you have run into?

Comment: I don't understand how to create a map like this in c ++
since I can't write files endlessly map within a map

Comment: It's like a tree.  You can't have a tree that contains a tree, but it can contain a POINTER to a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary depth, you're going to need some dynamic allocation.

```
struct Node
{
   map<string, std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
};

Node root;
```

Your bottom-most nodes will have no children.

We can't just write `map<string, Node> children` (even though the child `Node`s will themselves be dynamically allocated within the map), because `Node` is "incomplete" in the definition; in a sense, that's a limitation of C++ (though [you can work around this with a little more thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45719342/4386278)).

Answer (score 3):

Not to an arbitrary depth, no.
But, like most problems, you can solve it by adding a level of indirection.

For instance,

```
struct Tree
{
    std::map<std::string, std::optional<Tree>> children;
};
```